# How to configure jboss application server with eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, jboss

I am a new user of [JBoss](https://www.jboss.org/) application server, and need to configure it with [Eclipse](https://eclipse.org/ide/) IDE.

Answer (score 19):

To enable Eclipse to manage JBoss Application Server, you need to install the JBoss AS tools in Eclipse:

1. Start an instance of Eclipse.
2. Click Window > Preferences.
3. Expand the Server list, and click Runtime Environments.
4. In the Server Runtime Environments view, click Add.
5. In the New Server Runtime Environment dialog, click Download additional server adapters.
6. In the Install New Extension dialog, wait until the alphabetic list of server adapters is populated, then scroll down the list, and locate JBossAS Tools.
7. Click on this entry to select it, and click Next.
8. In the Review Licenses view, accept the license agreement, and click Finish.
9. Click OK to accept the restart warning.
10. The server adapter download is initiated, which may take a few moments.
    If you are presented with a security warning about unsigned content, ignore it by clicking OK.
    Once the server adapter is installed, click OK to restart Eclipse.

Comment: This is the best answer.

Answer (score 7):

JBoss Tools is what you are looking for. It's a plugin that integrates jboss with eclipse, so you can start the server, deploy apps, etc.

You can install it using eclipse marketplace, and there are tutorials out there that show you how to set up your server in eclipse, and deploy apps (for example http://www.mastertheboss.com/eclipse/jboss-eclipse/jboss-and-eclipse)

Comment: Thank you so much. The link you provided is really very helpful.